# Python 3 grouping

Tags: python-3.x

## Problem Description

I have a CSV file with 3 columns of data that I've imported and has the below data. I would like to be able to ask the user to enter a site number 25.361 for example. I then want to add the 3rd column Connections for each of the 9 cells found. So the site is listed as 25.631.x.x and I want it to add up everything so that it should equal 115,552 which is the result of adding all of them together for site 25.361.

## My Code

with open("C:/Python/Data/RttDataSouthwest.csv") as csvfile:

```
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

enbIDs = []
enbNames = []
enbRRCs = []

for row in readCSV:
    enbID = row[0]
    enbName = row[1]
    enbRRC = row[2]

    enbNames.append(enbName)
    enbIDs.append(enbID)
    enbRRCs.append(enbRRC)
```

siteSelection = input('Enter the eNB number below to search for [ex: 25.806.1.1]')

enbIndex = enbIDs.index(siteSelection)

theName = enbNames[enbIndex]

theRRC = enbRRCs[enbIndex]

print('The name of site', siteSelection, 'is:', theName,'and the RRC Connections are:',theRRC)

## My current output

Enter the eNB number below to search for [ex: 25.806.1.1] 25.361.1.1

The name of site 25.361.1.1 is: ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY and the RRC Connections are: 5856

## The below is the data in the csv file

Mkt.eNB.Cell ID.Carrier Name    Connections

25.801.1.1  ABQ_ACT 2230

25.801.2.1  ABQ_ACT 2970

25.801.3.1  ABQ_ACT 5915

25.801.12.2 ABQ_ACT 10917

25.801.22.2 ABQ_ACT 13462

25.801.32.2 ABQ_ACT 3062

25.361.1.1  ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   5856

25.361.2.1  ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   2251

25.361.3.1  ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   14289

25.361.12.2 ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   36518

25.361.22.2 ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   2603

25.361.32.2 ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   30118

25.361.14.4 ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   14400

25.361.24.4 ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   5453

25.361.34.4 ABQ_ALAMEDAPASEO-KASY   4064

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Check your delimiter if it's truly space and not comma(,) as the CSV is by name Comma-Separated Value.

```
import csv
with open(fileName, 'r') as carrier:
    mktList = list(csv.reader(carrier, delimiter=" "))

sum = 0
for item in mktList:
    # Give your own id number, possibly use int() depending on usage
    if item[0] == id:
        sum += int(item[2])

print(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Please accept my apologies as I'm a python beginner and I'm not fully understanding the replied program. I tried to copy and paste using my file path and it didn't output anything for me. I've updated the original posting with my current code and output.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I can find the results if I enter the full name 25.361.1.1 but I'd ultimately like to be able to enter 25.361 and get the results for everything beginning with 25.361 versus the current 25.361.x.x and then add the 3rd column of connections for a total count. Thanks again